# I am trying to give a path for my icon file but it shows an error?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
<Window x:Class="AFIC.View.WizardDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:AFIC_Controller.View"
    xmlns:res="clr-namespace:AFIC_Controller.Resources"
    Title="{x:Static res:Strings.WizardWelcomeWindow_Title}"
    ShowInTaskbar="True"
    Width="800"
    Height="600"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
    BorderBrush="#003B7B"
    BorderThickness="0"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Icon="/AFIC_Controller;component/Resources/Images/att_icon.ico"
    >

<view:WizardView Loaded="WizardView_Loaded_1"/>


</Window>
```

I am giving path for my icon file as Icon="/AFIC_Controller;component/Resources/Images/att_icon.ico" 
but after debugging it shows an error "Error    1   Could not find a part of the path 'C:\AFIC_Controller;component\Resources\Images\att_icon.ico'

Comment: Have you done any research into how a URI should be constructed?

Comment: try giving full path of the icon file instead like `C:\AFIC_Controller\Resources\Images\att_icon.ico` notice ;component is removed

Comment: try using .png image, i got same issue in silverlight 4, worked it by using .png image instead of other image types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I have noticed something:

```
<Window x:Class="AFIC.View.WizardDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:AFIC_Controller.View"
    xmlns:res="clr-namespace:AFIC_Controller.Resources"
    Title="{x:Static res:Strings.WizardWelcomeWindow_Title}"
    ShowInTaskbar="True"
    Width="800"
    Height="600"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
    BorderBrush="#003B7B"
    BorderThickness="0"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Icon="/AFIC_Controller;component/Resources/Images/att_icon.ico"
    >
```

This class seems to be in a namespace named `AFIC.View`, but you're trying to access an image from the `AFIC_Controller` namespace. When trying to access a content file from a referenced assembly, you need to use the following syntax:

#### Referenced Assembly Resource File

The pack URI for a resource file that is compiled into a referenced assembly uses the following authority and path:

• **Authority**: application:///.

• **Path**: The name of a resource file that is compiled into a referenced assembly. The path must conform to the following format:

AssemblyShortName[;Version][;PublicKey];component/Path

◦ **AssemblyShortName**: the short name for the referenced assembly.

◦ **;Version [optional]**: the version of the referenced assembly that contains the resource file. This is used when two or more referenced assemblies with the same short name are loaded.

◦ **;PublicKey [optional]**: the public key that was used to sign the referenced assembly. This is used when two or more referenced assemblies with the same short name are loaded.

◦ **;component**: specifies that the assembly being referred to is referenced from the local assembly.

◦ **/Path**: the name of the resource file, including its path, relative to the root of the referenced assembly's project folder.

So having a guess at your correct path, you could try this:

```
pack://application:,,,/AFIC_Controller;component/Resources/Images/att_icon.ico
```

If that still doesn't work, then please take a look at the many examples in the [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN... one of them *must* fit your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Icon file is included in your project and also change the **Build Action** of that icon file as Resources. For **Build Action**, go to the properties of that file.

Comment: Simply try with a Image control and set the icon as its Source, Check it is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

Add att_icon.ico in to Images folder through visual studio or any IDE you use. Copy and paste does not work.

Comment: Yes i have already done it using add existing item but didnt work :(